# ethers.js pass address as parameter. How to encode?

Tags: solidity, abi

My question is pretty simple

I'm trying to call a function in my smart contract from ethers.js

I just need to set a variable of type "address" in my contract.

Code:

```
//solidity
function setTokenX(address _tokenX) public {
    tokenX = _tokenX;   
}
```

```
//js

tokenX = '0x3fdaf6c54eba05edebed44c4f986f49a5de55113';

await mycontract.setTokenX(tokenX);
```

It works a weird way for some reason. On Etherscan my variable is displayed as

```
0x361d47ce0000000000000000000000003fdaf6c54eba05edebed44c4f986f49a5de55113
```

While in the in javascript I send the parameter as a string. What's the catch? Should I encode it and then abi.decode in solidity? How to do this with ethers.js?

Answer (score 1):

The contract should be working correctly.

The input look a little odd because it is encoded in the [solidiy ABI](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/abi-spec.html).

```
0x361d47ce0000000000000000000000003fdaf6c54eba05edebed44c4f986f49a5de55113
```

- `361d47ce` The first four bytes is the function selector. It encodes the function to be called.
- `0000000000000000000000003fdaf6c54eba05edebed44c4f986f49a5de55113` The next 32 bytes is the address parameter padded to with zeros.